# MVVM Toolkit - message receiver not firing?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-toolkit

Hello I got a simple message that I'm trying to deliver between classes:

```
  public class MainVM : ObservableRecipient, IRecipient<SaveMessage>
    {
        
        public void Receive(SaveMessage message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message.Value);
        }
    }
```

And this code in a different class:

```
[RelayCommand]
public void SendToDbSave()
{
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new SaveMessage(Result.ToString()));

}
```

Basically the message gets sent, but doesn't get received, the method doesn't get invoked.
Any idea why?

Comment: Did you register `SaveMessage`? You need to do so in the receiver (`MainVM`).

Answer (score 0):

try set `IsActive=true`.

the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observablerecipient) explained the IsActive Property:

"It exposes an IsActive property to activate/deactivate the viewmodel. In this context, to "activate" means that a given viewmodel is marked as being in use, such that eg. it will start listening for registered messages, perform other setup operations"

```cs
 public class MainVM : ObservableRecipient, IRecipient<SaveMessage>
 {
     public MainM()
     {
         IsActive=true;
     } 

     public void Receive(SaveMessage message)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(message.Value);
     }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).